# PuTTY "Incoming packet was garbled on decryption" and other errors

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, putty

I've got Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed in VMPlayer 6 on Windows XP SP3 - I created this using the mini.iso + OpenSSH Server. I can successfully SSH in via its NAT VMNet8 address 192.168.181.128.

After a few minutes I get the error "Incoming packet was garbled on decryption" or the connection just freezes. Things that make heavy use of the terminal seem to trigger this earlier.

Things I've tried to fix this.

- Specific Ubuntu version: Seen on both 14.04 and 14.10
- DHCP: tried static IP and DHCP
- VMWare network adapter: tried both e1000 and vmxnet3
- VMWare version: Tried VMPlayer 6 and 5
- VMWare tools: tried with and without installation
- VMWare network: tried NAT and Host only
- PuTTY version: tried 0.64 and 0.63
- PuTTY encryption option: tried 3DES different error: "No valid incoming packet found" and Blowfish - connection just hangs, no error
- PuTTY bugs options: Tried Ignore SSH-2 maximum packet size
- VMWare vs VirtualBox: Setup .vdk in a virtual box image => Problem disappears when using NAT with port forwarding but still exists if using Host Only Network option

I've run out of things to try... Any ideas? Part of the problem tracking this down is isolating it to a specific component.

I'm aware of other similar questions, but these either don't have answers or those answers don't fix the problem.

Comment: I'd also check SIP ALG is turned OFF on your modem / router as that can sometimes change bytes that look like your internal IP.. introducing corruption. http://www.surevoip.co.uk/support/wiki/:troubleshooting:sip_alg?redirect=no and https://wiki.ring-u.com/wiki/doku.php?id=disablesipalg some implementations trigger on any byte-stream not just VoIP.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this was fixed as the question is a bit old, but in my situation the cause was using `plink` in the proxy-settings of Putty. After I turned on the logging (the radio-buttons just below the proxy-command) `plink` had some plain text output about a non-cached server I wanted to use as a proxy.

As it also printed the full command line for `plink`, I basically copied and executed that in a command shell. I accepted the new server and the error went away in Putty.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the statistics on your network adaptors to see whether or not packets are being discarded due to errors in transmission being detected?

Comment: I checked in the Ubuntu guest using ifconfig. This didn't show any errors,dropped,overruns etc for RX or TX. I'm not sure where I can find this information in the Windows XP host.

Comment: Update. Used https://www.raymond.cc/blog/detect-packet-errors-in-your-network-lan-connection-status/ to add error counters in XP, sent/received both zero for VMNet adapters.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar errors and the solution was the following command executed from a Linux terminal or bash shell:

```
ssh -v -i path/to/my/key.ppk -o HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa,ssh-dss -o KexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -o Ciphers=aes128-cbc,3des-cbc -o MACs=hmac-md5,hmac-sha1 user@hostIP
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Some explanation of WHY this is a solution would make this a better answer. Use the EDIT button to make this more helpful.